# define new variable on fetch object - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this :

```
$sql = "select * from table limit 0,10";
...
echo $row->col1;
```

now, is it possible to create new vairable on this `$row` query?

for example :

```
$row->newCol = $myvariable ;
```

I don't want to use fetch as an array or else.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: is it possible to create new vairable on this `$row` query?

Comment: Try it. You will find out.

Comment: For that you have to try it out once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add but depends how you want to use it. For example have a look on below solution:
I have a table named `report` and i am selecting field `id` and `name` from the table after that I want to add new variable named `myvar`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testdb');

$sql = "select id, name from report limit 2";
$mydata = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($obj = &$result->fetch_object()) {
        $obj->myvar = rand();
        $mydata[] = $obj;
    }
}
print_r($mydata);
$result->close();
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Test 1
            [myvar] => 1666108130
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Test 2
            [myvar] => 270993283
        )

)
```

Here `$obj` is object of `stdClass` so you can add number of variable in it.

Hope this will help you.